# Global Action Layout Metadata/Deploy

Tags: deployment, metadata, ant, package.xml

We are currently doing our deploys using Ant. In our package.xml, we have "almost" everything set to "*".

We noticed that after a deployment, the Global Action layouts, as well the default values we had set for some fields didn't make to the target org.

Going through the documentation, I wasn't able to find a specific Global Action metadata type -> [Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm)

I found a comment under the Success Community where one user said: "Global Action / Publisher Layout is listed in the Page Layouts component type without a value in the Type column."

In our package.xml, for the Layout metadata type, we are "deploying" everything as below:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

Am I missing anything, or Global Actions, including their Page Layouts and default values are considered a "post deploy" step?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe global action layouts can be deployed via metadata. My metadata tool does not detect changes when I change a global actions layout.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before - get the list of Global Actions with:

```
<types>
    <members>Global-Global Layout</members>
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

But you can update the settings by defining each quickAction.
The key is you don't have to name each Object before the quickAction name.

```
<types>
    <members>NewTask</members>            <!-- Global Task -->
    <members>Account.NewTask</members>    <!-- NOT THIS -->
    <name>QuickAction</name>  
</types>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the Global Layouts this way

```
<types>
    <members>Global-Global Layout</members>
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to acquire Global Action Layout by retrieving QuickAction with the name of your global action. For example, using sfdx to retrieve NewCommunityCase Global Action:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "QuickAction:NewCommunityCase" -u desired-org
```

The QuickAction metadata I received has description of quickActionLayout with columns and items.

Answer (score 0):

Just use quick action in pakcage it will retrieve the quickActionLayoutItems you can customize the fields.

```
<types>
    <members>NewTask</members>
    <name>QuickAction</name>
</types>
<version>36.0</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Global Publisher Layout assignment is on Profile level, can be also deployed by profile

```
<layoutAssignments>
    <layout>Global-Global Layout</layout>
</layoutAssignments>
```